# Deploying an apollo & react full stack app

Tags: deployment, apollo-server, react-fullstack

My current project uses apollo-server on the backend & react on the frontend: https://github.com/harryd05/earthquake-hunter. I can't find any tutorials on how to deploy this type of project - does anyone have any advice on how to do this? *(If possible, the hosting should be free e.g. heroku or netlify)*

Comment: Hey Harry, your question is too vague and can be answered with a google search: it will give you just that, a list of tutorials to deploy your Apollo and React FullStack app. I would have linked the Google search in here, if it couldn't be (rightfully so) interpreted as sarcastic and disrespectful. But please do come back to SO once you have a concrete well-definded technical problem on your hands following a tutorial

Comment: Apologies - new to SO, I spent an hour yesterday trying to find a tutorial that deploy an apollo server with react frontend, all the tutorials I found needed the backend to be express & wondered if the creator of the tutorial I was following (loosely) for the project had deployed the project & he could give me advice on how to do so - I now realise I should have just emailed him! But I thought someone might have done similar before & might be able to give me advice on SO.